# Checkbox update in GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

When people search on my website using a `GridView` I would like to have a `checkbox` column that they click on which will change the value in a column called `STATUS` to `U`.  I'm having a heck of a time finding code that works so I was hoping you guys could help.  I'm a COMPLETE NOOB so please be descriptive if you know the answer.

Code for `Checkbox` button - Currently when I search it comes back saying that it cannot convert string to `boolean`.

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Successful Contact?">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" checked='<%#Bind("status")%>'  AutoPostBack="true" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" checked='<%#Bind("status")%>'
                   Enabled="False" /></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the vb code

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    For Each GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim value As Boolean
        value = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked
        Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=i3FCC01;Integrated Security=True;").ConnectionString
        Dim com_sql As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim insertSql As String
        insertSql = "Update CallQueueFCC Set Status='U' where Id = @id"
        Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", value)
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myConnection.Close()
        End Using
    Next
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding Status value for check box checked attribute which takes Boolean value.

But status has string value as you are binding string to Boolean it is throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kiran mentioned earlier, status has a string value so you need to do some firefighting in the row databound event.

**Markup**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Successful Contact?">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"   AutoPostBack="true" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
               Enabled="False" /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Code behind**

```
   Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
  'Evaluate the state of the check box, true when status =U , and false otherwise
  Dim itemstatus As Boolean=If(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status"), True, False)
  Dim CheckBoxItemTemp As CheckBox=CType(e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
  CheckBoxItemTemp.Checked=itemstatus
  End if


  If e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit Then
 'same as above but  now for edit item template
  Dim editstatus As Boolean=If(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status"), True, False)
  Dim CheckBoxEditTemp As CheckBox=CType(e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
  CheckBoxEditTemp.Checked=editstatus
  End if

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Abide, but now I'm as confused as ever.  Visual studio doesn't like the e.RowIndex, but also I'm not sure how that code does anything because I don't see it triggering any sql update command to update the SQL value to U.  Pulling my hair out, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have updated my answer.My bad.It should have been e.Row in lieu of e.RowIndex.The code actually does something.It clears the error you are having about  string to Boolean conversion.You will still have to hook to your updating logic in the grid row updating event, which you have already done.Let me know if this is still unclear.